# e is empty on "exception Exception as e" Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception

When I use:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

print(e) just prints an empty line and I don't know why, it happens with asyncio exceptions.

Comment: Which exceptions does it occur for?

Comment: The problem is actually where you raise the exception. You aren't passing anything to exception.

Comment: i.e asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError. Maybe the problem is just on the asyncio exceptions. @Axe319

Comment: print type(e) and e.args, this should give enough insight to debug what is going on

Comment: That specific exception has no `__str__`  method. If you look in your python installation folder in the `Lib/asyncio/exceptions.py` file you will see that it just inherits from the base `Exception` class. You could `print(e.__doc__)` or as @OlivierMelançon mentioned, `print(type(e))` for the class name.

Comment: Ok, thank you both !